# Сохранение изменений в подчиненной БД

Tags: c#, access

Ошибка при сохранении изменений (или удалении) в подчиненной таблице.

Есть две таблицы "Клиенты", "Объекты" - связь "один ко многим".
К каждой таблице подключен bindingNavigator.
При удалении/изменении данных в головной таблице, все нормально работает (сохраняю Update).
А в подчиненной, если удалять или редактировать строку, выдает ошибку при попытке сохранить, можно только добавлять новые записи.

Comment: Данная ситуация возникает потому что видимо существует связь между главной и подчиненной таблицей. Чтобы избежать возникновения данной исключительной ситуации необходимо либо у записей в главной таблице сделать ссылки на другие записи в подчиненной(т.е. которые удалять не будем) либо сделать каскадное удаление записей в случае удаления записей в подчиненной. Без кода ошибки тут можно только гадать))

Comment: Каскадное удаление сделано в самой БД (Acces). При удалении "Клиента" удаляются все его "Объекты". Так же можно добавить "Объекты" определенному "Клиенту" и сохранить, а вот удалить или изменить "Объект" нельзя. Выдает ошибку при попытке "Update". Ошибка - "Для обновления требуется действительный Update Command при передаче коллекции DataRow с измененными строками".

Comment: не задано свойство UpdateCommand, соответственно прога просто не знает запрос, при помощи которого происходит обновление

Comment: Пересмотрел кучу форумов, есть описание как описать UpdateCommand если Адаптер был создан в ручную. У меня Адаптер сгенерен автоматом, и при попытке прописать как в примере, говорит что таких команд не существует. Может есть ссылка на пример с Acces-ом?